# javascript using a fetch with a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

I need to get datas sometime from a file and othertime from an api with a fetch,
I tried to use a ternary operator

```
import datafromFile from './Data/mydata.json';
let useDatafile = false; 
const dataToUse = useDataFile ? dataStored : fetchData().catch(console.error).then(result=>result);
```

but is going wrong on the following lines of code cause my dataToUse is still at promise
my fetchData function looks like :

```
const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await fetch(targetUrl, {
                method: "GET"
            });
            const myreturn = await response.json().then(result => {
                console.log('myreturn '); console.log(result);
                return result.data;
            });

        };
```

I used a ternary operator cause

```
 var dataToUse='';
 if (useDataFile) {
     dataToUse = dataStored;
   }
    else {
          //that's is probably horrible..
          fetchData().catch(console.error).then(result => dataToUse = result);
          }
```

gave me a dataToUse empty .. :-(

thank you for considering my code with indulgence I am really new to javascript, thank you for reading me and for your help

Comment: You cannot use the value from `fetchData` like that.

Comment: `fetchData` has no return statement

Comment: Don't use `then` when you want to use `await`

Comment: yes ! thanks for the comments now I do 
    const fetchData = async () => {
                const response = await fetch(targetURL, {
                    method: "GET"
                });
                return await response.json();
            };
and like it's a Promise
 fetchData().then(receved => dosomething(receved));